# Twitter bootstrap 3 RC2 - Navigation in IE8 not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC2 to create a navbar at the top of my page which works fine except in IE8.

In IE8 is acts like as if the browser was made small, so that the menu collapses for mobile view. But this is not the case.

Now i know that TB3 is still a work in progress. But i'd like to know if anyone have a solution for this here.

---

If you want to check my problem with IE8, then look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/DnwJN/embedded/result/

(you need the direct link, because the JSFiddle it self doesn't work with IE8)

And here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DnwJN/

---

You'll see that the navbar works fine in every other browser. Even IE9. But not IE8. And TB3 does support IE8. They only dropped support for IE7 and below.

Anyone have a solution for this problem?

---

## The code from the fiddle

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hope this helps...

From http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ :

```
    <!-- Enable responsive features in IE8 with Respond.js (https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) -->
    <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 8):

Also, take note of the fact that you have to include this code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="${rc.getContextPath()}/js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="${rc.getContextPath()}/js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

**AFTER** all the css has been included for it to work properly.

Answer (score 6):

after adding the html5shim i was still having issues with the dropdown in ie8.
found this article https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6548 which explains that filters are getting in the way.  bootstrap has a default filter on the navbar so you must clear that.  here's what worked for me.

```
.navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.open>.dropdown-toggle, .navbar-inverse .nav
li.dropdown.active>.dropdown-toggle, .navbar-inverse .nav    
li.dropdown.open.active>.dropdown-toggle,
.navbar, .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner {
    background-color: #15317E;
    border-color: #252525;
    filter:none;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, but you don't need the `background-color` and `border-color` :)

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla Bootstrap 3 uses jQuery 2 by default. So in order to get it working in IE8, you have to change jQuery version to less than jQuery 2.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Include these two scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
```

Most importantly, use a web server to view your site (with http:// or https:// protocol, as file:// protocol would break respond.js' execution).

Comment: It's now 2017. Your tip about using the old jquery is the only thing that has worked for me, with Bootstrap 3.3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<!-- HTML5 shim for IE backwards compatibility -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<![endif]-->
```

to your code and check or use modernizer.js or normalizer.js.
Also check http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers where it says to include respond.js to enable media query support.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was my version of jquery. jQuery 2.0.2 didn't work well with bootstrap 3 in IE8 but jQuery 1.9.1 worked perfectly. Didn't test it with jQuery 1.10.1. Switch the version of jQuery and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

hey use modernizr js because i8 and earlier versions does'nt support  bar's because it us html5.For that use modernizer js. :)

[modernizer](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that it uses `nav`. If a browser doesn't support an element, like `nav` in this case, then it's just treated as a `div`. You can also see that from this example, where to navbar is created out of divs only: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/. I think it's a bug in one of the media queries.

Comment: yep change the visiblilty classes for ie(in media queries)

Answer (score 0):

mainly check meta http-equiv tag, if it is not include in your file, add this

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

bootstrap3 workes fine with ie 8 only you have make sure to add respond.js , html5shiv .

like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to make sure your CSS is included via `<link>` and not `@import`

Answer (score 0):

Now, in 2017, I just found out something that suggests that the various responses above--- involving html5shiv, respond.js and jquery<2.0---  are *all* necessary.

It's this: go to the latest Bootstrap (now 3.3.7) [here](http://getbootstrap.com/), then scroll down to [collection of examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), and then click on the first "Navbars in action" on the left. You'll find that the Dropdown menu item works.

Now take a look at the page source. And at the bottom, what do you see? You see jquery 1.12.4, that's what you see... not the latest which is 3+.

You can do a search for "jquery drop support for ie8" to see the numerous announcements.